# Removing last object in NSMutablearray

Tags: iphone, arrays, object, nsmutablearray

Is there any why to remove last object in NSMutablearray without crashing app? :D

Comment: Have you tried reading NSMutableArray's documentation? (Hint: no, you haven't.)

Comment: I had been reading the documentation and didn't realize that removeLastObject was MANDATORY.  I find your question helpful. Wait, no, it isn't mandatory.  Because removeLastObject (in an array of size one) crashes just the same.  Hooray. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure: send the `removeLastObject` message to a valid `NSMutableArray` object which is not empty.

Comment: hahahah ok... Usually I am reading documentation but I was looking in code for 1 hour and didn't know what to do... I did't think that apple made something like method removeLastObject... I was using [array removeObjectAtIndex:3] and it was crashing xD

Comment: You don't even have to read the documentation -- just take a look at the header file -- NSMutableArray.h. Actually, for almost all cases when you want to do something with a cocoa object and aren't sure how to do it, it's much easier and informative to look at the header file for the class.