# How to remove last object from NSMutableArray in ios without app crash

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray

Here is my code

```
 (void)viewDidLoad

{
    descriptionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"I'm not perfect,imake mistakes,i hurt people. But when i say sorry,i really mean it.",
                                                               @"Single",
                                                               @"jon@live.com",
                                                               @"+91 9731244748",
                                                               @"jon.Korta",
                                                               @" 05 Common Friends",
                                                               @"Facebook", nil];

}
```

In UITableView Datasource Method

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
 static NSString *cellidentifier = @"CellID";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];

    if (cell == nil)

    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

     cell.descriptionLbl.text = [descriptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}

return cell;
}
```

CustomCell.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionLbl;
```

I used CustomCell to display descriptionArray objects in UITableView cell.From the descriptionArray i want to remove "Facebook" object in the UITableView cell.
Anybody can guide me.Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Format your code.  2) Why does it crash? (What exception is being thrown?) 3) Where's the code that removes the entry?

Comment: [descriptionArray removeLastObject];

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'
Am getting this exception in my code

Comment: `NSMutableArray` has method to remove last object `[descriptionArray removeLastObject];` you can use that.

Comment: simple use like that to remove last object - [descriptionArray removeLastObject] or   [descriptionArray removeObjectAtIndex:descriptionArray.count-1];

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498707/removing-last-object-in-nsmutablearray

Comment: [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498707/removing-last-object-in-nsmutablearray) Here given to your question's answer.

Comment: I thought you are writing for loop on descriptionArray right

Comment: If you have written any for loop then please provide that code in question

Answer (score 4):

if you really want to remove the last object from your array just do any off the following

```
[descriptionArray removeObjectAtIndex:descriptionArray.count-1];
```

or

```
[descriptionArray removeLastObject];
```

and make sure that number of cells should be `descriptionArray.count-1`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the last object by using `[descriptionArray removeLastObject];`. 
**After removing the last element you need to reload the table view**. Dont forgot to reload the table view.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `descriptionArray` as your data source for `cellForRow` method, you need to make sure that `numberOfRow` is also returning your array count. So when you remove the last object in array and called table reload data it doesn't crash.